# Cast Callback Parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to cast SKNode to my own subclass of SKNode (Flag).

```
scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("flag") {
    node as Flag, stop in
        node.methodAvailableToFlagObject()
}
```

The code above throws an error. Is there a solution?

I'm trying to avoid having to do this:

```
scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("flag") {
    node, stop in 
        let realNode = node as Flag
        realNode.methodAvailableToFlagObject()
}
```

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: Since it looks like you don't really need the `stop` param anyways, you could just leave out the entire `in` line. In the first like you could use this instead:`let node = $0 as Flag`

Comment: Good point. I generally don't do that for clarity, but you're right that it does simplify the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only upcast to a parent type:

```
var closure : (Subclass) -> () = {
    (first : Superclass) in
}
```

you cannot downcast to a subclass

Comment: So in this case there is no solution since I have no control over the function definition?

Comment: Correct. I think your only slightly better solution is what @ackStOverflow suggested with the inline casting

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I'm missing something here? I know it's not the case that "you cannot downcast to a subclass", one-half of the Type Casting section in the Swift Programming Language book is dedicated to safe downcasting.  :)  Can somebody explain what it is about this case that would make it any different?

Comment: @ackStOverflow I just mean you can't downcast by declaring the parameter as a subclass. You can of course downcast manually within the implementation (which his example is already doing)

Answer (score 3):

what about

```
scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("flag") {
    node,  stop in
    if let flag = node as? Flag {
        flag.methodAvailableToFlagObject()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast in a method chain by using parentheses, e.g.

```
(node as Flag).methodAvailabletoFlagObject()
```

...and you can even use the optional form of casting if it's possible the cast will fail, and then combine that with optional chaining:

```
(node as? Flag)?.methodAvailableToFlagObject()
```

Comment: Nice tip. Still doesn't quite help me since that could cause redundant code. Going got accept the answer from @drewag.